# Prove that a function is both odd as well as even.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the function

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-\sqrt {\vert ln \{x\}\vert}}- \{x\}^{\sqrt {1/\vert ln \{x\}\vert}},  & \text{wherever it exists} \\
\{x\}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

where $\{x\} $ denotes fractional part of $x$. Prove that $f(x)$ is odd as well as even.

I am not getting any idea over how to start approaching the problem. I tried using $f(-x) +f(-x)$  to see whether odd or not but got messed up badly.  Somebody please help.

Comment: $2$ is odd as well as even?

Comment: Just my problem. Is it possible ?

Comment: There are no integers that are both odd and even.  The only function that is both odd and even, satisfying $f(x)=f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$, is the zero function.

Comment: First, how many functions can be *both* even and odd.  $f (x)=f (-x)=-f (x) $.  Surely that's unusual.  Perhaps the are asking you to prove something much simpler.

Comment: I also guess that the function might reduce to f(x)=0 since it is the only odd and even function

Comment: Do you know any way to relate general exponential functions to exponentials with base $e$?

Comment: Guys I have proved the statement If x is an integer because the first part of the function isn't defined on integers.

Comment: It is true via some slightly tricky algebra. My hint above about exponentials is a good one.

Comment: Since $\ln \{x\}<0$ then $|\ln\{x\}|=\ln  \frac 1 {\{x\}} $.

Comment: To be a little more explicit about my hint, if $a^b = e^c$, then what is $c$?

Comment: The top term exists exempt when x is an integer.  To compare e^stuff to {x}^stuff take the ln of each.  You get -root (|ln {x}|) for one and root (1/|ln {x}|)x ln {x}.  Show those are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not hard to see that for $f$ to both even and odd, $f$ must be identically $0$ on its domain. The first branch of $f$ is undefined whenever $\ln\{x\} = 0$, which occurs when $x$ is an integer; in this case, $f(x) = \{x\} = 0$.

If it is defined, then
$$e^{-\sqrt {\vert ln \{x\}\vert}}- \{x\}^{\sqrt {1/\vert \ln \{x\}\vert}}= e^{-\sqrt {\vert \ln \{x\}\vert}}-e^{ \ln \{x\}\sqrt {1/\vert \ln \{x\}\vert}}$$
$$= e^{-\sqrt {\vert \ln \{x\}\vert}}-e^{-\vert \ln \{x\}\vert\sqrt {1/\vert \ln \{x\}\vert}}=0,$$

since $a^b = e^{b \ln{a}}$ and $\vert \ln \{x\}\vert = - \ln \{x\}$.